# Does "fastboot flash recovery <recovery-file.img>" command work with any android device?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot

The command is used to flash a recovery. Do you have to use odin like tools to flash it or you can just use adb?

Thank you

Comment: This is no duplicate. You just don't understand

Comment: Andykl, Please explain to @keepclam or to all of us why it is not a duplicate. Your question is of low-quality as well. Add your search and research to show that you did put efforts to find answer. See [ask].

Comment: This question is about flashing a recovery which has nothing to do with flashing  a system, which is what another question is about. One requires unlocked bootloader, another does not. So one can depend on fastboot protocol, while another not.

Comment: Please explain what is low quality question? Theses are weird terms that the portal is using. My question does include everything needed to understand it, but no, i have to include redundant info.

Comment: I recommend  you read more about what fastboot mode does. **Fastboot is not discriminatory**. If you can flash system partition using it, then you can flash any other partition too, including recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to clear the confusion, fastboot and adb are two different modes/states. Now to answer your question, it depends whether your phone supports the fastboot protocol (all Android phones support adb, this is not the case for fastboot).

If it so happens that your smartphone is fastboot capable, then the `fastboot flash recovery file.img` command will work.